# How to traverse a column of a gridview using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is binded dynamically on run time. I need to traverse a column of gridview on client side. I have passed the id of gridview to the javascript function but I have no clue as how to traverse a particular row.

I m calling the javascript function from my code behind as -

```
btnInsert.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return IsValidEntry(" + gridview.ClientID + ")");
```

right now I m catching ID of the control of a particular row and passing it to another javascript function as -

```
function IsValidEntry(Status) 
    {
        var strErr='';
        if(document.getElementById(Status.id).innerHTML == "Dev in Progress")
        {
            strErr+='<br>* Develeopment should be completed first.';
            document.getElementById('schValidation').innerHTML = strErr;                
            jQuery("#schValidation").show('slow');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Which is working fine.but now I need to traverse this whole column.

A link or some sample code will be very helpful.

Thanks

Akhil

Comment: You want to loop on all rows or just a particular row? And same for  columns like you want to access any particular column or all?

Comment: You want to check all columns or row?? You've written traverse in column in your subject line, but in body you want to traverse in row!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jquery.  Give the column a CSS class and use the each iterator.

```
    $(function() {
        $('.className').each(function () {
            // do something...
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can traverse your gridview rows and column like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#GridViewID tr').each(function () {
                alert($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text()); //get column1 value
                alert($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text()); //get column2 value
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by -

```
function IsValidEntry() 
      {
        var len = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gdScheduleNew').rows.length;
        var i;
        for (i = 2; i <= len; i++) 
        {
            if(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gdScheduleNew_ctl0" + i + "_lblStatus").innerHTML == "Dev in Progress")
            {
                //Code here
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: these ids are not hard coded... the value of i is changing everytime

Comment: I meant the `'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gdScheduleNew'`.

Comment: Yes i have hardcoded the id as this id is fixed and its not gonna change.

Comment: What if you change the id of your server control? What if you wrap it in another .NET control? All of these will cause .NET to generate a different client id. You're better off generating the javascript server side or using [inline tags] (http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx) to get the client ids.

Comment: ohk you are absolutely right... that might generate additional problems in future... i understand now.. thanks a ton